# Infopath farm loading error first time while deploying solution or uploading farm template through CA in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Infopath farm loading error while deploying WSP or uploading infopath farm through farm template. same time infopath farms all site collections in the web application keep on loading and after sometime throwing time out error .

Please help on this issue.

Following solutions I have tried but no luck:

1. Increased Maxdata connection roundtrip `Set-SPInfoPathFormsService-MaxDataConnectionRoundTrip 40000`
2. Under the Infopath Farm Services increased Maximum Data connection
   time out to 90000
3. Data connections response size increased 1500 kb to 9000 kb
4. SharePoint web service root application pool credentials changed 
   local service to Domain account
5. Web application added into host entry
6. Disableloopback check added
7. Warmup script executed
8. Finally ran the following script:

> ```
> $f = Get-SPInfoPathFormsService
> $f.Properties.Add("AllowEventPropagation", $false)
> $f.Update()
> ```

After loading few minutes throwing time out error with correlation:

[image]

Please guide me how to resolve the issue.
[Following link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SPBestWarmUp-Warmup-e7c77527#!) preferred to prepare warm up script

Comment: Please provide ULS-Logs for the provided Correlation. This will help answering this question.

Comment: yes take here output from Merge-SPlog -Correlation YOURID. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In my observation from last few days, This issue not related with deploying the solution or retracting the solution. It's purely related with IIS, Because when I do IISRESET or Restart the server then only Infopath farm not loading it's unable to connect the GETUserProfileByname.

Related ULS log:

The following data connection (GetUserProfileByName) has exceeded the maximum configured time limit. This threshold can be configured by using the SPIPFormsService -MaxDataConnectionRoundTrip PowerShell commandlet
Web Request: Ends url=http://ServerName/sites/SiteCollection/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx action=http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService/GetUserProfileByName
Please help me.